# Deleting a key in Parse upon clicking "Delete" in table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

What I have is a table view with different cells that display different messages with other people you're chatting with. Upon swiping the cell to the left, a `Delete` option shows up. I want to be able to delete both the cell itself as well as the `Room` associated with it in Parse. This is what I have so far:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        //Delete messages here
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Message")
        query.whereKey("Room", equalTo: ??????)

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

This function displays the `Delete` option, and when I click it, I want it to delete the cell it was clicked in. Does anyone know what goes inside the query? I have a `Message` class and I want to delete the `Room` key that's associated with the cell I delete.

Comment: Is the message the only one in an indexPath? If so you could just findObjectInBackground with ObjectId. Right now your limiting your results to return only the rooms equal to whatever the name of the room would be. If you don't want to delete the whole room and it's messages and you just want to delete a particular message in that room you would have to narrow it down as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Try  this :

```
var dataToDelete:NSMutableArray = []  // this is a dummy array just to replicate your array 
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle:   UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
    var object  = dataToDelete[indexPath.row] as! PFObject
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()
      object.delete()
    }
 }
```